# VBA Excel: What is the object type when doing a For/Each of a range?

Tags: excel, foreach, vba

I am trying to do a loop through the columns of two rows to add data from one sheet to another.  This is additional data that was not dealt with in the previous code (since the previous code had specific logic to populate it).

I tried creating a sub to loop through the current rows on each page, but I am getting a byreference error.  One of the ranges is the whole destination row, which is offset (incremented) every time it is populated.  The other range is the source material, and covers a column in the source sheet. Other columns are accessed via offset.  It am doing much of my work in a For/Each of the source range.

When I create the sub and try to pass the second range (bar), I get the error.  I am trying to access the 'bar' object in the For/Each, so that both pages are dealing with the same row. This doesn't appear to be working.

Do I need to reDim, or find some other way to pass the appropriate range to the looping function?

Relevant code:

looping sub (very simple) -

```
Private Sub LoopThru38(thisRow As Range, sourceRow As Range)
    Dim counter As Integer

    For counter = 1 To 35
        thisRow.Cells(1, 8 + counter).Value = sourceRow.Cells(1, 19 + counter)
    Next counter
End Sub
```

Where I pass it -

```
ElseIf bar.Cells(1, 19) = prevComp And bar.Cells(1, 19).Value = foo.Cells(1, 2).Value Then ' compare if prev and current comp match
    ' add other DTCs of this component
    destRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = idNumber
    destRange.Cells(1, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
    destRange.Cells(1, 2).Value = CStr(objectNumber + dotNumber - 0.01) & "-" & CStr(dashNumber)
    destRange.Cells(1, 3).Value = "3"
    destRange.Cells(1, 5).Value = bar.Cells(1, 6).Value '
    destRange.Cells(1, 6).Value = bar.Cells(1, 10) ' foo.Cells(1, 3).Value & " - " & foo.Cells(1, 4)
    destRange.Cells(1, 7).Value = bar.Cells(1, 11)
    destRange.Cells(1, 8).Value = "FMI " & bar.Cells(1, 11) & ": " & bar.Cells(1, 13)
    LoopThru38 destRange, bar ' loops through rest of 38 col to populate export sheet
    Set destRange = destRange.Offset(1, 0)
    idNumber = idNumber + 1
    dashNumber = dashNumber + 1
End If
```

Original declarations of the ranges -

```
With ThisWorkbook
    Set WS = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    Set Columns_38 = .Worksheets("Joe")
    Set dtcList = .Worksheets("Fred")
    Set spnList = .Worksheets("Martha")
End With
'...cont
Set srcRange = dtcList.Range(dtcList.Cells(2, "A"), dtcList.Cells(lastRowSrc, "A"))
Set destRange = WS.Range(WS.Cells(2, 1), WS.Cells(2, 42))
Set spnRange = spnList.Range(spnList.Cells(6, 1), spnList.Cells(lastRowSPN, 1))
```

spnRange is where I seem to be having issues. It is in the second For loop (bar), and that is where I get the source data for the output.  It doesn't want to pass 'bar' into the sub though. Do I need to pass the whole range in there, and figure out where I am at?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a `For Each` in your code anywhere?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I left that part out. The IF if nested inside, and I have to edit the code to keep from putting any confidential info in there. I will do it if necessary, but I figured knowing that 'bar' is an element of looping through sourceRange would be sufficient. If more code is needed, I can do that too.

Comment: If you think there may be a problem with the For/Each, then yes, you should show it to us.  Also what line specifically is throwing the error?  Are you saying that it is the last one above (`Set spnRange..`)?

Comment: @RBarryYoung It is throwing the error at the call to the LoopThru28 sub. Since it is stated that 'bar' should be a range, I guess I need to know why I am getting a byreference error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare `bar` as a Range in the calling loop.  If you do not, then it isn't a Range object, but rather a Variant that *contains* a Range object.  This works the same *until* you try pass it to a function/subroutine argument that is declared ByRef as a specific object-type, like Range.

This will throw an error, because the compiler cannot tell if it really will be a Range type at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

The object type when using a `For Each` loop on a `Range` is `Range`.

```
Sub DisplayFirstTextInRange(WithinThisRange as Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng in WithinThisRange
        If rng.Text <> "" Then
            MsgBox rng.Text
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

A more useful way of iterating through ranges may be by Row:

```
 Sub DisplayFirstTextInFirstColumnOfRows(WithinThisRange as Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng in WithinThisRange.Rows
        If rng.Cells(1,1).Text <> "" Then
            MsgBox rng.Cells(1,1).Text
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```